# One Command/Script to Upload X Files Using FTP

Tags: python, shell, upload, ftp

If there is a thread that answers this question I'm sorry for being a fool (reading through the titles and the threads that look like they might have been [about] the same as mine, none of them were close enough for me to be able to figure it out for myself.

I'm looking to have a script (I suppose bash or python would be preferable, since I'm working on learning Python; but at the moment really I'd settle for almost anything).

From a directory (so I'm already "cd"'d to the directory; so it can adapt to whichever directory) I'd like to be able to:
RUN_SCRIPT "File 1", "File 2", "File 3", "File 4", "File 5"..."File (n-1)", "File (n)"
or
RUN_SCRIPT "File *"
and have it (in some form) accomplish the same thing I'm doing when (at the moment) from the directory I'm using:
    ftp -inv << FTP
    open ftp.HOST.com
    user USER_NAME PASSWORD
    mput "FILE NAME"
    bye
    FTP
And having to do that in multiple shell windows (one for each file).

Being able to have it run X instances of ftp at a time would be nice, but isn't at all necessary (just being able to tell it to do all of them at once is fine).

Thanks in advance!  This site is epic (can't wait for the time when I can be answering questions instead of just asking them).

**Side Question:** If what I want to be able to do isn't possible for some reason I can't possibly comprehend; is there a way to smash the command list I have into one line?

Comment: Glad you like the site, but this doesn't seem to be a programming question - it probably belongs on superuser.com.

Comment: Okay, I'll make sure it's ready for superuser and post it there if it is once I get back from class.  But (and I'm sure this is me) I'm a little confused.  I'm asking about how I might make a script that would let me do this--what distinguishes this from a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

I would pick a different FTP client. The libcurl library (and its "curl" command line program) has a FTP upload method.

Comment: You mean something different than the server's "mput" ftp stuff?  I wasn't even aware there was an alternative (since I can't use FXP).